# Designing a class named Triangle in Java

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Design a class named Triangle that extends GeometricObject. This class contains:

a. Three double data fields named side1, side2, and side3 with default values 1.0 to denote three sides of the triangle.

b. A no-arg constructor that creates a default triangle.

c. A constructor that creates a triangle with the specified side1, side2 and side3.

d. The accessor methods for all three data fields.

e. A method named getArea() that returns the area of this triangle.

f. A method named getPerimeter() that returns the perimeter of this triangle.

g. A method named toString() that returns a string description for the triangle.

The formula for computing the area of the triangle is:
s = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
area = s(s – side1) (s – side2) (s – side3)

The toString() method is implemented as follows:
return “Triangle: side1 = “ + side1 + “side2 = “ + side2 + “side3 = “ + side3;

Write a test program that prompts the user to enter three sides of the triangle, a color, and a Boolean value to indicate whether the triangle is filled. The program should create a Triangle object with these sides and set the color and filled properties using the input. The program should display the area, perimeter, color, and true or false to indicate whether it is filled or not.

I have tried this question and the codes are as below, but there is an error in the Triangle class and i do not know how to fix it.

```
 //Triangle Class
      public class Triangle extends GeometricObject 
     {
         private double side1 = 1.0;
         private double side2 = 1.0;
         private double side3 = 1.0;
         
          public Triangle()
          {
              
          }
         
          public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3)
         {
             this.side1 = side1;
             this.side2 = side2;
             this.side3 = side3;
             
         }
         
     
         public double getSide1() 
         {
             return side1;
         }
     
         public double getSide2() 
         {
             return side2;
         }
     
         public double getSide3()
         {
             return side3;
         }
     
         public void setSide1(double side1) 
         {
             this.side1 = side1;
         }
     
         public void setSide2(double side2) 
         {
             this.side2 = side2;
         }
     
         public void setSide3(double side3)
         {
             this.side3 = side2;
         }
     
         public double getArea()
         {
             double area,s;
             s = (side1+side2+side3)/2;
             area = Math.sqrt(s * (s- side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));
             return area;
         }
     
         public double getPerimeter() 
         {
             return side1 + side2 + side3;
         }
     
         public String toString()
         {
         return " Triangle: Side 1 = " + side1 + " Side 2 = " + side2
                + " Side 3 = " + side3;
         }
         
         
     }
```

```
//GeometricObject Class
   public class GeometricObject
{
    protected String color = "white";
    protected boolean filled;
    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled)
    {
    this.color = color;
    this.filled = filled;
    }

//getColor()
    public String getColor()
    {
    return color;
    }

//setColor
    public void setColor(String color)
    {
    this.color = color;
    }

//isFilled
    public boolean isFilled()
    {
    return filled;
    }

//setFilled
    public void setFilled(boolean filled)
    {
    this.filled = filled;
    }
}
```

```
//Test Program
public class Lab82
{
    private double side1 = 1.0;
    private double side2 = 1.0;
    private double side3 = 1.0;

        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter three sides of the Triangle");
        double side1 = input.nextDouble();
        double side2 = input.nextDouble();
        double side3 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the color of the Triangle");
        String color = input.next();

        System.out.println(" Is the Triangle filled? Reply with 'True' or 'False' ");

        String filled = input.next(); 
    
        
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
       

        System.out.println("The Triangle Sides are \n side 1: " + triangle.getSide1() + "\n Side 2: " + triangle.getSide2() + "\n Side 3: " + triangle.getSide3());
        System.out.println("The Triangle's Area is " + triangle.getArea());
        System.out.println("The Triangle's Perimeter is "+ triangle.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("The Triangle's Color is " + triangle.getColor());
        System.out.println("Is the Triangle filled? " + triangle.isFilled());

    }
}
```

The errors that i get are these :
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When your class is extending another which doesn't have a default (no-argument) constructor, you should tell java how to construct its parent class when constructing an instance of the child class. In your case, java doesn't know what to give for `color` and `filled` to the parent constructor.

You should call the parent constructor in all of the child class's constructors using`super` keyword like this:

```java
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject 
     {
          // ...
          public Triangle()
          {
              super(someColor, someFilled);
          }
          // ...
     }
```